How can I restart a job in VASP software?
I'm running an AIMD (Ab initio molecular dynamics) calculation in the NVE ensemble with a specific initial kinetic energy (without using temperature control). My job stopped before the simulation time was completed. I have the velocity and coordinate data, but the WAVECAR file can't be read. How can I restart the job?

I suppose that you don't need the WAVECAR to continue the calculation, just copy CONTCAR to POSCAR, the CONTCAR should have the velocities from the last step. However, you may need to converge the electronic density again if you don't have WAVECAR. from the manual (https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Molecular_dynamics_calculations), you can check the first paragraph. It is better to do that in a new folder to avoid losing your previous calculation.

Thank you @Jaafar Mehrez  I'm doing the same thing—converting CONTCAR (with velocities) to POSCAR and running the job. But I'm noticing that when I split a 2000 fs trajectory into two 1000 fs segments, the outcomes are different from just running the whole 2000 fs in one go.

What outcomes are you referring to?
